# How do I properly update my Postgres Database in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

**The Problem:** *syntax error at or near "$"*

**The Context:** My App does two CRUD operations - Update & Read Data from a Postgres database. It successfully reads data from the database and displays on the frontend. However, it fails to update the database when I query it to do so. It throws an error that *'syntax error at or near "$"'*.
So far, I have failed to debug the error successfully.

**The Stacks:** Postgres, Node.js, React

**The Query **(BackEnd)**:**

```
//burrow a book
app.post("/books/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        
        const copies = await pool.query('SELECT copies FROM books WHERE book_id = $id', [id]);
        
        const stock = copies - 1;
        
        const updateBook = await pool.query("UPDATE books SET copies = $1 WHERE book_id = $2", [stock, id]);
        

        const allBooks = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM books");
        
        res.json(allBooks.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

**The Function**(FrontEnd)**:**

```
async function burrowbook(id) {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/books/${id}` , {method: "POST"});
            
            console.log(res);

            // setbooks(jsonData);
            // console.log(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);

        }
    }
```

**The Full React Component**(FrontEnd)**:**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';



const ListBooks = () => {

    const [books, setbooks] = useState([]);

    async function burrowbook(id) {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/books/${id}` , {method: "POST"});
            
            console.log(res);

            // setbooks(jsonData);
            // console.log(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);

        }
    }

    const getBooks = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/books");
            const jsonData = await response.json();

            setbooks(jsonData);
            // console.log(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);

        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getBooks();
    }, []);




    return (<Fragment>

        <div class="container ">
            <h1 class="text-center mt-5">Wakanda Library</h1>

        </div>

        <table class="table table-hover table-dark text-center mt-5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Book ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                    <th scope="col">Year</th>
                    <th scope="col">Stock</th>
                    <th scope="col">Burrow</th>
                    <th scope="col">Return</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {books.map(book => (
                    <tr key={book.book_id}>
                        <td>{book.book_id} </td>
                        <td>{book.title} </td>
                        <td>{book.author} </td>
                        <td>{book.publish_year} </td>
                        <td>{book.copies} </td>
                        <td><button
                            className="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-md"
                            onClick={() => burrowbook(book.book_id)}
                            >
                            Burrow
                </button></td>
                        <td><button
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-md"
                            // onClick={() => returnBook(book.book_id)}
                        >
                            Return
                </button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </Fragment>);
};

export default ListBooks;
```

**The Full index.js script**(BackEnd)**:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const pool = require('./db');

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //req.body

//ROUTES//

//login user



//register user



//list of books in library
app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allBooks = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM books");
        res.json(allBooks.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});


//burrow a book
app.post("/books/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        console.log(id);
        const copies = await pool.query('SELECT copies FROM books WHERE book_id = $id', [id]);
        console.log("b");
        const stock = copies - 1;
        console.log("c")
        const updateBook = await pool.query("UPDATE books SET copies = $1 WHERE book_id = $2", [stock, id]);
        console.log("d")

        const allBooks = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM books");
        console.log("heee")
        res.json(allBooks.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});


//return a book
app.put("/booksreturn/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const { copies } = req.body;
        const returnBook = await pool.query(
            "UPDATE books SET copies = $copies WHERE book_id = $id",
            [copies = parseFloat(copies) + 1, id]
        );

        res.json("Book was returned!");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});

//list of books in users possession

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Baba... server don start on top port 5000.")
});
```